# CARTO.js / ReactJS: Showing and hiding layers on toggle

Tags: leaflet, javascript, carto, carto-js, react

I have a the following layer:

```
class DataLayer extends Component {
  static contextTypes = {
    map: PropTypes.object, // Leaflet map
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    const { client } = this.props;

    // Craete source, styles and layer with the given props
    const cartoSource = new carto.source.Dataset('dataset');
    const cartoCSS = new carto.style.CartoCSS(style);
    const layer = new carto.layer.Layer(cartoSource, cartoCSS);

    // Add them to the client and to the map
    client.addLayer(layer);
    client.getLeafletLayer().addTo(this.context.map);
  }


  // ... missing methods to handle styles/source updates


  render() {
    return null; // No need to render anything :)
  }
}

export default DataLayer;
```

Then, I have the following component that shows the Layer component:

```
class Canvas extends Component {
  state = {
    center: [40.6552398976147, -73.959729361534119],
    zoom: 11,
    checked: false
  };

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    // Setup the client in the contructor with our user and apiKey
    this.cartoClient = new carto.Client({
      apiKey: "APIKEY",
      username: "LOGIN"
    });
  }

  onClick(e) {
    this.setState({
      checked: !this.state.checked
    });

  }

  render() {
    const { center, zoom } = this.state;

    return (
      <div>
        <div>
          <label className="switch">
                  <input
                    type="checkbox"
                    onClick={this.onCheck.bind(this)}
                    checked={this.state.checked}
                  />
                  <span className="slider" />
                </label>
        </div>
        <div>
          <Map center={center} zoom={zoom}>

            <Basemap attribution="" url={CARTO_BASEMAP}/>


            {this.state.checked ? <DataLayer client={this.cartoClient}/> : null}
          </Map>
        </div>
      </div>
    )
}
export default Canvas;
```

Everything works great for the first try, when the checkbox triggers `checked` to be true and the `DataLayer` component mounts. However, when I uncheck the checkbox and expect the DataLayer component to be unmount, it doesn't. I believe the reason is a missing method to handle it in the DataLayer component once it's been updated.

How to make DataLayer component to "unmount" when the toggle is set to false?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Carto's client.removeLayer(layerName) doesn't work, so apparently I had to come up with this solution:

```
componentWillUnmount() {
    const { client } = this.props;
    let array;
    array = client.getLayers();

    const indexedById = array.reduce((a, { _id }, i) => {
      a[_id] = i;
      return a;
    }, {});
    let layerId;
    layerId = indexedById.LAYERNAME;

    client.removeLayer(array[layerId])
  }
```

Where `LAYERNAME` is the id of the layer once created:

```
const LAYERNAME= new carto.layer.Layer(cartoSource, cartoCSS, {id: "LAYERNAME"});
```

Comment: This in unnecessary if you keep the reference to the layer, that I guess you can do with no problem in your example. You can check it working here https://codesandbox.io/s/nkno85woo4

Answer (score 0):

In `componentWillUnmount` you can call `client.removeLayer`.

Take into account that the element where Leaflet draws is not unmounted (I guess Leaflet is managed in the `Map` component) so the tiles of the layer have already been drawn. Call `removeLayer` to be sure that it's correctly refreshed with no content from that layer.

https://carto.com/developers/carto-js/reference/#cartoclientremovelayer

Comment: I tried adding client.removeLayer() to componentWillUnmount(), and I toggle the component by either showing it (if checkbox is true) or hiding (: null) in the parent React component. But again, once rendered, it stays there :/ Could you please add a detailed example in your answer?

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/mqm0j22o38 My structure of layers is based according to this.

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/nkno85woo4 Here you go. The point is that `client.removeLayer` needs the layer as an argument. If you keep the reference to the layer, you pass it to the function and everything will work as expected.